# What role an Android Service should play in the MVP pattern?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mvp

I am developing an Android app that does Human Activity Recognition.

It basically works like that - Service constantly reads the accelerator data and stores the recognized activity (i.e. Walking, running) in a database. The user can see all of the recognized activities in an `ListView` in activity (accesses the database). Every User table in the database has a pa_goal (physical activity goal) field which the Service reads from the database and does some checks.

The user, of course, can change this goal from an activity. Since I will be implementing the MVP architectural pattern.

I am unsure where to put the Service? It surely isn't View. Any advice?

Comment: its part of your data model, isn't it?

Comment: @pskink the service only stores the data to the database. This is what is does. Dose that mean I should consider it as Model? I am confused since the purpose of the MVP is to separate the android code from the java code so if I threat my Service as Model am I not doing it wrong?

Comment: sort of, you are using a custom `ContentProvider`? if so, look at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-contentproviders/ (and https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture in general)

Comment: @pskink No, I am using Realm database warped around in a DataManager which I am going to inject with Dagger into the Service. This is my plan, at least. Thanks! I  will have a look at the links

Comment: anyway, take a look into the first link i posted, it can be helpful...

Comment: The service should definitely be inside model. You then pass the data to the presenter which will eventually display it inside the view. It can be easily done using rxjava

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev I must say that is an awesome question. It has kept bugging me for quite some time. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a clean architecture, which is what I am assuming you are using MVP for, there is the idea of separating the framework from the business logic. This is essentially what a normal presenter allows you to do.

In this case its not a view you are dealing with but the principle is similar. You don't want all your business or application logic mixed in the Android code when you can separate them out for nicer, more single responsibility classes. So I would say that while it isn't a view you should still have a presenter type class (probably better to be called controller or manager maybe).

This class would be a POJO that controls how your service behaves which is easily testable with standard junit tests and service mocks. This class and the service could then be put into its own feature package and interact with the back end models the same way as your presenters.

So, in summary, the role is of another feature of your app that sites alongside the other features (which are usually just views in my experience).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much,  Alex! It really helps! :)

Comment: I have just one question. Am I right to think that this class - Controller should be passed a Context (to start the service for example ) and thus it will contain android specific code?

Comment: Ideally you should not have to pass it a context. As the context is android code you want to keep it in the service to make the controller easier to test. Don't let the Context become a God object ;)

Comment: I see. Yes,  I will keep that in mind. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @MungoRae could you show some sample code for this approach?

Comment: @MungoRae nice solution. It's a very simple and awesome solution! Maybe my mind wasn't fresh when I commented. :D

Comment: was thinking of just injecting a presenter into the service

Answer (score 4):

This article helped me in a similar situation, although may not be exactly yours, the idea is the same:

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-bound-services-and-mvp-12ca9f70c7c7

Basically, the author works around the fact that a bound service is tightly coupled to an activity, and it adds extra lifecycle calls to it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Jose. Will certainly take a look at the article! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation. Finally I decided to do something like this:

Activities or Fragments are out of scope, they do not know anything about MVP BUT i am going to use an event bus like Otto to send signals/events, So:

My classes which extends some kind of Presenter know nothing about Android Context but they will have an MvpView interface, with only onAttachPresenter and onDetachPresenter.

The class which extends Service will have a Presenter attribute and implements some MvpView interface with onSucess, onError, onStart, onComplete or something like that and same events for Otto (onSucessEvent, onErrorEvent, onStartEvent, onCompleteEvent).

So when I need to do something the Activity or Fragment will start the service, the service will "start" or talk with the Presenter and when the presenter finish with success will call to mvpView.onSuccess() and store the info inside a local DB with SQLite (storeIO maybe) and finally the Service will invoke Otto and pass the signal (without any data on it), probably onComplete.
Finally the signal will be catched by my UI (fragment maybe) and retrieve all the info inside a DB in SQLite.

So when the onSucess happens the UI will show the latest and best data BUT when onError happens will (at least) show some info (or not if you want) saying to the user "there was a problem but at least you can see something", bot onSuccess and onError will call onComplete after all.

Do not know if this is the best solution but in this case I think I am not going to deal with Activities or Fragments lifecycle and do not care about onSaveInstance and restore data when the user rotates the device. It will always fetch the latest data inside DB, and if something happens (no internet connection) you can at least show something when you receive the onComplete Signal.

Some facts I am still thinking:

- The Presenter won't be a singleton class
- Presenter knows nothing about Context but yes with MyApplication class
- What happens if for one screen (Fragment) you have differents service with differents onSuccessEvents? Simply use some kind of action as an ID, to identify them.
- Never make the Activity Fragment implements the MvpView, you will have to deal with the lifecycle.

Comment: I see. It is a good solution to he problem. I decided to create another class called Controller which requires a Context as a parameter (I will have to test that class with roboelectric) and my Presenter has an instance of this class so it dose not know any android specific code and it is able to start a service and stop it :). As for the live cycle of the Presenter, it is not too bad in my case.

Comment: I do not know but I don't see a bad thing if the fragment or activity starts the service. Android knows android stuff but MVP doesn't.